# Copy only files from root directory in Gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I am trying to copy all files from just the root directory, not the sub folders. This is currently what my gulp task looks like.

```
const dev = 'app';

const dist = 'dist';

const htmlDev = `${dev}`;
const htmlDist = `${dist}`;

const sassDev = `${dev}/scss`;
const sassDist = `${dist}/css`;

const jsDev = `${dev}/js`;
const jsDist = `${dist}/js`;

const tplDev = `${dev}/template-parts`;
const tplDist = `${dist}/template-parts`;

gulp.task('copyfiles', () => {
  console.log(`Copying files now`);
  gulp.src('app/*.+(php|css|png|txt|md|dist|html)')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(htmlDist));
});
```

How can I simplify this in order to have the task run proper?

Comment: Assuming your htmlDist variable is defined somewhere (or perhaps you meant 'htmlDist') I tested your code and it works as expected - no subdirectories under app are copied.

Comment: @Mark yes, htmlDist is defined and currently, my code works fine but what I am trying to do is instead of having to add on more files as they come, I want my task to just look for all files and not folders in the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all files in a directory just use:

```
return gulp.src('app/*.*')
```

No subdirectories will be included.  I added the `return` as you will probably need it sooner or later.  BTW, if you wanted all subdirectories you would use :

```
gulp.src('app/**/*.*')
```

Comment: That kind of works but for some reason, it is not copying over .svg or .xml files.

Comment: It does work. I cleaned gulp cache and it worked just fine. Thanks, @Mark!